# Can liquibase runners reference properties from deploy IT dictionaries?

Tags: liquibase, deployit

I have created a new `liquibase.Runner` and filled in the db credentials properties using placeholder which should be filled from a DeployIt dictionary. But those properties values are not being resolved, like `url`, `username`, etc?.

Please suggest does `liquibase.Runner` supports dictionary placeholder replacement or not?

Answer (score 1):

As `liquibase.Runner` is a Container in XL Deploy, it does not support placeholder replacement. Placeholder replacement is only supported on the conversion from Deployable to Deployed. If you want to externalize the settings, please put them in a `liquibase.properties`, and point the `liquibase.Runner.liquibaseConfigurationPath` to the properties file.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/xebialabs-community/xld-liquibase-plugin) here.

Comment: Thank you very much.Can you please tell me where can i find liquibase.properties and liquibase.Runner.liquibaseConfigurationPath in DeployIT.As i cannot see in common,Deployment etc tabs of runner.

Comment: Which version of DeployIt are you using, and which version of the plugin?

Comment: DeployIT version is 5.1.4 and liquibase version is 3.0.5

Comment: Hi Hiery  where can i find liquibase.properties and liquibase.Runner.liquibaseConfigurationPath in DeployIT ?

Comment: They should be in the 'common' tab of the `liquibase.Runner` in the repository editor. Are you sure you have installed https://github.com/xebialabs-community/xld-liquibase-plugin this plugin?

Comment: are you saying environment variables in common tab ?.For testing purpose define one variable username and referenced using ${username} but didn't work.